# Catch py_compile.PyCompileError, and convert to string

Tags: php, python, try-catch, exec

I'm trying to compile a python script and record any syntax errors

I have a script called test.py that looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import py_compile
try:
    py_compile.compile("answer.py")
except py_compile.PyCompileError as e:
  print(e)
```

answer.py is just a self contained script that doesn't do anything except print something(for now)

i also have a php exec command in a php file that runs test.py, problem is php exec doesn't get returned anything by

`print(e)`

I'm guessing because e here in PyCompileError isn't a string or something weird with the format, the result simply comes back empty "". When I played around with it it seems to be an object, not sure how to convert that to a string.

I tried putting it into a string but it's not working, if I change e into a string like `print("You have errors")` I get the correct output, so it's not my php but I want the syntax errors on the lines. Not even sure if I should be using compile() for this

Comment: Read (again) the documentation of `py_compile.compile()`. Hint: `doraise`

Comment: Never mind this question I figured out how, just `print(e.exc_value)` ,  the documentation on py_compile kinda sucks so it took me a quite a while to figure it out. Also i just saw that comment and I did try do raise but I didn't know what value of PyCompileError was the one to print, I thought it'd be msg but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, basically I needed doraise=True and then get `print(e.exc_value)`

I did initially have `doraise=True` before people think I was lazy and not reading the documentation, but I didn't realize exc_value was the variable that had the message(I was trying to get e.msg) so I turned it off since it said by default it prints to stderr with it off, and I tried to work from there.

Please ignore